# DataGridView Row selection and variable saving wierd issue

Tags: c#, datagridview

This code is working, but sometimes select one row and save variable and simetimes not.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int Index = 0;
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            Index = e.RowIndex;
            dataGridView1.Rows[Index].Selected = true;
            DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[Index];
            nazev = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        }    
    }
```

All options of DataGridView are default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you sort the columns of your grid maybe it loses his index. Try this:

```
string yourVariable = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Same problem. It happens on unsorted grid . I think sorting isn't a problem.

Comment: WOW i just solve this. I just changed CellContentClick to CellClick and it starts work 100%. Thanks anyway